# Yml file in cpanel for deploying multiple subfolder and files

Tags: bash, github, yaml, cpanel

I have configured CPanel with GitHub repository, but I can not write my .cpanel.yml file properly, because there is no execution when I try to deploy HEAD commit. Here it is my .yml:

```
---
deployment:
      tasks:
        - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/tita8rfx/public_html/try/protected
        - /bin/cp -r components $DEPLOYPATH
        - /bin/cp -r controllers $DEPLOYPATH
        - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/tita8rfx/public_html/try/assets
        - /bin/cp style.css $DEPLOYPATH
        - /bin/cp app.js $DEPLOYPATH
        - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/tita8rfx/public_html/try/protected/views
        - /bin/cp -r app $DEPLOYPATH
```

I also have tried:

```
---
deployment:
      tasks:
        - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/tita8rfx/public_html/try
        - /bin/cp -r /protected/components $DEPLOYPATH
        - /bin/cp -r /protected/controllers $DEPLOYPATH
        - /bin/cp /assets/style.css $DEPLOYPATH
        - /bin/cp /assets/app.js $DEPLOYPATH
        - /bin/cp -r /protected/views/app $DEPLOYPATH
```

What I want this code to do is to modify the **following folders**:

- /home/tita8rfx/public_html/try/protected/components
- /home/tita8rfx/public_html/try/protected/controllers
- /home/tita8rfx/public_html/try/protected/views/app

and the **following files**:

- /home/tita8rfx/public_html/try/assets/style.css
- /home/tita8rfx/public_html/try/assets/app.js

But there is no execution or error and I cannot get what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I have found my problem. Here it is the solution. I had to be more adverbial in the paths from which the updated data should be get.

```
---
deployment:
      tasks:
        - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/tita8rfx/public_html/titanbg-hs.com/protected
        - /bin/cp -r /home/tita8rfx/repositories/hsapp/protected/components $DEPLOYPATH
        - /bin/cp -r /home/tita8rfx/repositories/hsapp/protected/controllers $DEPLOYPATH
        - /bin/cp -r /home/tita8rfx/repositories/hsapp/protected/models $DEPLOYPATH
        - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/tita8rfx/public_html/titanbg-hs.com/assets
        - /bin/cp /home/tita8rfx/repositories/hsapp/assets/style.css $DEPLOYPATH
        - /bin/cp /home/tita8rfx/repositories/hsapp/assets/app.js $DEPLOYPATH
        - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/tita8rfx/public_html/titanbg-hs.com/protected/views
        - /bin/cp -r /home/tita8rfx/repositories/hsapp/protected/views/app $DEPLOYPATH
        - /bin/cp -r /home/tita8rfx/repositories/hsapp/protected/views/tpl $DEPLOYPATH
```

I hope this will help someone with the same problem as mine.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the issue is how the repository is structured and how the paths are expressed and evaluated.

It looks like the repository may be structured like this:

```
/ (repository root)
├─assets/
│ ├─app.js
│ ├─style.css
├─protected/
  ├─components/
  ├─controlers/
  ├─views/
    ├─app/
```

The first example does not work as expected because the items that are being copied are sub-directories other directories relative to the current working directory.

```bash
# this...
/bin/cp -r components $DEPLOYPATH
# should be this...
/bin/cp -r protected/components $DEPLOYPATH
```

The second example does not work as expected because the items to copy are expressed as absolute paths due to the leading "/".

```bash
# this...
/bin/cp -r /protected/components
# copies this...
/protected/components

# while this...
/bin/cp -r protected/components
# copies this...
/home/tita8rfx/repositories/hsapp/protected/components
```

A simpler, correct way to express this `.cpanel.yml` file would be:

```bash
---
deployment:
      tasks:
        - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/tita8rfx/public_html/try/assets
        - /bin/cp assets/app.js $DEPLOYPATH
        - /bin/cp assets/style.css $DEPLOYPATH
        - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/tita8rfx/public_html/try/protected
        - /bin/cp -r protected/components $DEPLOYPATH
        - /bin/cp -r protected/controllers $DEPLOYPATH
        - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/tita8rfx/public_html/try/protected/views
        - /bin/cp -r protected/views/app $DEPLOYPATH
```

Since the question specifies that the target directories are to be modified, they presumably already exist. If there's a possibility that some of these directories don't already exist they would need to be created first, or the copying would not work as expected.